# Seperate action page for new layouts in yii

Tags: layout, yii, action

I am a yiibie, I created a new layout named "landing.php" in layouts folder, but when i run it, it opens the index.php. How can I have a separate action page for landing.php.
So either i run main.php or landing.php they should be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the layout for each action in the controller adding in the function action

```
$this->layout = "layoutName";
```

or for entire controller adding the attribute

```
public $layout = "layoutName";
```

This work in Yii 1.x and Yii 2.x